# UICollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath: only works for rows 6+

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Running into a weird issue, I have a collection view with a Custom Flow Layout and some custom insets. In my viewDidLoad: I am loading data for my collection view and determining which item should be scrolled to, and then in my viewDidLayoutSubviews: I am calling `[collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:scrollToIndex atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];` If the row for my scrollToIndex is 6 or greater everything works as expected, if its 5 or less it always scrolls me to row 0 and I cannot figure out why this would be happening, any suggestions would be much appreciated I have been searching around for potential solutions for hours.

Comment: Are you adding datasource objects of collectionView into different sections?

Comment: @ParasGorasiya no the collection view just has 1 section

Comment: Please show some more code to get better idea.